# Checking if year is leap with c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am very new to C#, so my question may be silly but I realy can't solve it by myself & googling. I need to check if year is leap, so:

```
<mso:if runat=server condition='<%# DateTime.IsLeapYear(2000)%>'>
```

works fine. But I need to get Year from somewhere, e.g. MS SQL:

```
 YEAR(getDate()) AS yarr
```

...

```
<mso:if runat=server condition='<%# DateTime.IsLeapYear(<%#Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "yarr"))%>)%>'>
```

**Error:**

> CS1040: Preprocessor directives must appear as the first
>   non-whitespace character on a line

But why? Don't see any space before year.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You used scriptlet `<%# %>` twice which are nested, remove one.

```
condition='<%# DateTime.IsLeapYear(Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "yarr")))%>'
```

Comment: unfortunately no, "Server tag is not well formed"

Comment: One right parenthesis was missing from my answer, test with updated code.

Comment: Tbh better way is checking year without MS SQL: <script language="C#" runat="server">int is_leap_year = DateTime.Today.Year;</script>...<mso:if runat=server condition='<%# DateTime.IsLeapYear(is_leap_year) %>'>